# Creating a shell script to run Java program

Tags: java, bash, shell

I used a shell script to run a Java class.
My script contains

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar jobs/job.jar
```

These are my failed attempts to run it.

```
[root@]#sh testapp.sh
Unable to access jarfile jobs/job.jar
```

if I just do this at the command line it works fine

```
[root@]#java -jar jobs/job.jar
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you run the script from the same directory ?

Comment: It is not recommended to routinely run things in super user mode (aka root).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the absolute path to your JAR file, e. g. `/root/jobs/job.jar`.

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to get the current dirname and get in there with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname "$0"`
java -jar ./job/job.jar
```

Comment: This seems like the actual right answer, because using an absolute path is not an option when you plan to move the files (or even share it)